# Can two nodes have the save child node in zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper. Is there any way for two nodes to share the same child node? Or is there some concepts (in zookeeper) similar to symbol links in file system?
For example, /parent_node_1 has /parent_node_1/child_node. /parent_node_2 has /parent_node_2/child_node. Can /parent_node_1/child_node **be the same** with /parent_node_2/child_node **physically**?

Comment: Not that I know. However, nothing stops you from making a symlink convention (symlinks in Unix are conventions, roughly).